# How to understand this code(about javascript 'var')

Tags: javascript

What does "var" do in JavaScript?

```
(function (a) {
  var a;
  console.log(a); // why output 1?
})(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

As RJM said, it declares a variable in the local scope. More specifically to the confusion you seem to be having, it outputs 1 because you are immediately invoking the function by passing in the 1. That gets set to the variable `a`. Calling `var a;` after `a` is already set effectively does nothing.

To give a bit more context to that statement, variable declarations in javascript are hoisted to the top of the scope. Read more about it on MDN:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting

Comment: when we use var declares a variable which is exists, what does js engine do? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It declares a variable in the local scope.

Comment: why not undefined?

Comment: As Damon points out, it is just redeclaring the argument variable `a` in that function.  In your example, the `var a` declaration really has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

**var** define a new variable inside function scope, then `a` can not be accessed outside function context.

You can take a look to [Closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) for more information.

I hope that helps :D

Answer (score 0):

In the code provided, you are running a self-executing anonymous function.

```
(function(){
  //Code goes here
})();
```

Anything defined inside the preceding parenthesis is executed immediately. Variables and functions defined outside of the anonymous function cannot reach the everything defined inside.

You are passing the integer 1 to the self-executing which is defined as `var a`.

```
(function (a) {
  var a;
  console.log(a); // why output 1?
})(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

It sets A as a variable and automatically sets it as the boolean "true".